# What does leveling your equipment get you?

Tags: spiral-knights

After every mission in Spiral Knights, you earn "Heat" which upgrades your weapons and armor. What does leveling your equipment do? Does it make it more damaging / more protective? Do certain activities require items of a certain level?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At Heat Lvl 5 and 10 your weapons get a small but meaningful bonus, and yes if you took the time to look at a Lvl 1 item you see the blue bar and some dark blueish bar after that. Each level fills that up a bit. For crafting the higher tier items eg.Tempered Calibur it need the standard stuff plus a Calibur. An Acended Calibur requires a lvl 5+ Tempered Calibur. A rule of thumb is if you're not at the highest tier of gear and your stuff is lvl 10 get new stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, That is true.

ALSO!! At 4 star the gear is required to become lvl 10 before being able to be transmuted into 5 star gear. Many players see this as a pain. (It is!!) But.if you take the time to do good missions it will be simple. ( A little hint) If you find trouble doing this do 1 of 2 things.  Either, Equip all lvl 10 gear so your other weapon gets all the heat. Or do a mission with ONLY 2 PEOPLE, and let that person die many many times, because whenever you die you lose 30% of your heat and the player reviving (you) gets that 30%.